# scala spark - do not throw exception in retry method

Tags: scala, apache-spark, exception

```
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}
def retry[T](n: Int)(fn: => T): T = {
  Try {
    return fn
  } match {
    case Success(x) => x
    case Failure(f) => {
      Thread.sleep(3000)
      if (n > 1) {
        retry(n - 1)(fn)    
      } else {
          //custom error handling - dont throw exception 
         println("error")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When compiling the above retry method it returns the below error

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: T
         println("error")
            ^
```

The goal is to not throw an exception in case of failure. How can this be achieved using the above retry function?

Comment: Well if all the retries failed you need to signal that somehow? Maybe return an `Option[T]` instead of a plain `T`

Comment: I am trying something like this, will keep you posted if it works
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}
def retry[T](n: Int)(fn: => T): Option[T] = {
  Try {
    return Some(fn)
  } match {
    case Success(x) => x
    case Failure(f) => {
      Thread.sleep(3000)
      if (n > 1) {
        retry(n - 1)(fn)    
      } else {
         None
      }
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

Below is an updated version of the code you posted in the comments:

```scala
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

def retry[T](n: Int)(fn: => T): Option[T] = {
  Try(fn) match {
    case Success(x) => Some(x)
    case Failure(f) => {
      Thread.sleep(3000)
      if (n > 1) {
        retry(n - 1)(fn)
      } else {
        println(f)

        None
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

#### What have I changed?

Where you had:

```scala
 Try { return Some(fn) } match { }
```

I have changed to:

```scala
Try(fn) match { }
```

This is because we shouldn't return here but instead check whether or not `fn` threw an Exception. Since we are not returning we don't need to wrap with `Some`.

---

```scala
case Success(x) => x
```

is now:

```scala
case Success(x) => Some(x)
```

This is to satisfy the return type of `Option[T]`

---

```scala
else { None }
```

is now:

```scala
else {
  println(f)

  None
}
```

This was on based what you mentioned in the question: "`//custom error handling - dont throw exception`" and `println("error")`.
Here I am instead printing `f` which will contain specific error information for the Exception that occurred.

---

#### Wh did you see `error: type mismatch` ?

This was because `println` returns the `Unit` type; it can be thought of as not returning anything at all, at least not anything we can reference.